# How do I stop the program from replicating a line that has /r/n in front of it?

Tags: java

Parts works apart from when I read in /r/n in front of some characters it does what I want then replicates the line and keeps /r/n.

I have written a program and I want it to scan through a file and replace special characters with values I want.

Please is there something I am missing?

Have a look look at the code below.

```
public synchronized String theMessage() {
    int type;
    String rmCarReturn;
    String newLine;
    String val;
    String str = "", fin = "";
    String par;
    int index = -1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(message);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        str = sc.nextLine();
        if (str.isEmpty())
            ;
        else if (str.charAt(0) == '<') {
            par = str.substring(1, str.indexOf('>'));
            if ((index = param.indexOf(par + "//" + messages)) != -1) {
                par += "//" + messages;
            } else
                index = param.indexOf(par);
            if (index < 0) {
                logger.info("Param " + par + "not found");
                sc.close();
                throw new paramNotFoundException(par + "not found");
            } else {
                type = param.getType(par);
                val = param.getValue(par);
                if (type == 0)
                    fin += val;
                if (type == 1) {
                    fin += loadData(par);
                }
                if (type == 2) {
                    fin += calculateCorrelation(par);
                }
                if (type == 3) {
                    fin += loadFunctons(par);
                }
            }
        }
        if (str.charAt(0) == '/')
            fin += str.substring(1);
        //Carriage return
        if(str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(),4)).equals("\\r\\n")){
            rmCarReturn = str.substring(4);
            newLine = (String.format("%n") + rmCarReturn );
            fin += newLine;
        }
        if((str.substring(str.length() - 4).equals("\\r\\n"))){
            rmCarReturn = str.substring(0, str.length()-4);
            newLine = rmCarReturn + String.format("%n");
            fin += newLine;
            }
        //End of Carriage return
        else {
            fin += str;
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    data.nextIteration();
    return fin;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to treat input as text, don't use `Scanner`. Use `InputStream` instead and treat your input as bytes.

Comment: If you rephrase the sentence that starts with "_Every thing works apart from..._" so that more people can understand it, you would increase your chances of getting answers.

Comment: @Siguza I can't agree with such advice.  If he's dealing with characters, then he needs to replace characters with characters.  That means a Reader / Writer or something based on one of these two classes.  A Stream reads and writes bytes which will fail in unexpected ways when replacing bytes that could be only "part" of a character.  It is obvious he's treating it as text, with the string lengths and search for ASCII control characters.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to think of is keep the original line (you've already red) in a variable, then extract the content you need via replacing the new line `/r/n`. Once you've processed what you need just continue to iterate the file reading it line by line. Something like this:

```
try( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( ... ) ) {
  reader.lines().foreach( line -> processLine( line ) );
}
```

in your `processLine(String line)` pass and extract the content of the line using String's `replaceAll("(\\\\r)?\\\\n", "")`.